# Adding Maven repository from local disk

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I want to use an external folder as a library. That folder(mvnLib) has `maven-metadata-local.xml` and a `.pom` and a `.aar` files in it and documentation says I can use it like this:

```
allprojects { 
  repositories {
​     maven {
      url "../mvnLib"
     }
  } 
}
```

But id doesnt work and I get this error:

```
Could not find method ​implementation() for arguments [com.app.two:plib:1.3.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I cant find this type of `Maven` repository documentation. Can I use a `Maven` repository on disk? Is this correct? Why Im getting this error? Is there a automatic procedure to adding libraries like this to lower error rate?

***Update:***

mvnLib folder structure is:

```
[Project Root]
.gradle
app
mvnLib
   com
     app
        two
           plib
              1.3.2
                   prlib-1.3.2.pom
                   prlib-1.3.2.aar
              maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Documentation says put the mvnLib in the root of project. then on the project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects { 
  repositories {
​     maven {
      url "../mvnLib"
     }
  } 
}
```

Then on the app level build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.app.two:plib:1.3.2'
```

I do all of these but i get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define directories as Maven repositories as long as they fit the structure (comparable to the local repository). This is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762617/927493 .

Comment: Thanks to you answer. But I cant get it. That repository created already. It has own .pom file. I updated my question.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with how you write the url in your `build.gradle` (starting with `file://` or not).

Comment: I tested everything but result is the same. My  mvnLib folder is in the project root, and build.gradle file too. is this correct to refer library like url "../mvnLib"? I tested every model possible, but not succeed. As i know, all of problem is about path. if I remove that part from project build.gradle i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the repository declaration.
It complains about the dependency declaration and the fact that `implementation` is not known.

Did you add the `java` or `java-library` plugin to your project? Or another plugin for doing JVM based development?
If you did not, then the error is expected, it just means that a configuration named `implementation` was not added to the project.